# join two tables in sql with different rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two sql queries, which gives me two tables with different quantity of rows, I need join them - just mutual to display together two tables

table 1

```
  row1      row2
  ==============
  12        gfd
  13        jf
  14        gfd
  15        jhhh
```

table 2

```
  row3      row4
  ==============
  18    gjkd
  11    jfyty
```

Result

```
row1    row2     row3         row4
======================================
  12    gfd      18           gjkd
  13    jf       11           jfyty
  14    gfd     
  15    jhhh
```

The data in each table are completely different and have different field names. I use *Oracle DB*, query need to be use in *iReport*.

Comment: are you using `MySQL` or `SQL server`?

Comment: Which RDBMS? mysql or sql server or something else?

Comment: I adjusted question, I try suggested desitions from answers but could adjust for iReport, maybe someone work with it?

Answer (score 4):

Use [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

```
select * 
from table1 t1
LEFT OUTER  join table2 t2
on t1.row1=t2.row3
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b15ec/2)

**EDIT1:**

This works in MySQL

This is for your updated Question

## [SQL Fiddle new demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dbd9/1)

```
select row1,row2,row3,row4
from
     (select row1,row2,@i:=@i+1 AS rn
      from Table1,(SELECT @i:=0) r)t1 
left join
     (select row3,row4,@j:=@j+1 AS rn
      from Table2,(SELECT @j:=0) r )t2
on t1.rn=t2.rn
```

Comment: In the sample provided, the columns `table1.row1` does not match `table2.row3`.

Comment: @Gerardo: The question was edited/changed, after Joe answered.

Comment: @GerardoLima: I have updated my answer for his updated question.. Plz check

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the change, but this solution cannot guarantee the order of the rows.

Comment: @GerardoLima: please check the link "SQL Fiddle new demo"

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you want to join the two tables by the order of the rows in each table. I am sorry, but SQL doesn't have the concept of an implicit order of rows inside a table and there's no way in SQL to concatenate the columns of two (or more) tables without any column to allow the JOIN.

The closest things you could accomplish in SQL is:

- `CROSS JOIN` between the two tables. That would repeat each row from table1 to each row of table2:

```sql
SELECT t1.row1, t1.row2, t2.row3, t2.row4
FROM table1 t1
CROSS JOIN table1 t2
-- row1  row2    row3  row4
-- ----  ------  ----  ------
--   12  gfd     18    gjkd
--   13  jf      18    gjkd
--   14  gfd     18    gjkd
--   15  jhhh    18    gjkd
--   12  gfd     11    jfyty
--   13  jf      11    jfyty
--   14  gfd     11    jfyty
--   15  jhhh    11    jfyty
```

- Create another (auxiliary) column and store the "order" of your rows in each table (there are many ways to do it using cursors, sequences, ...). Then use those columns to build an `OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT t1.auxOrder1, t1.row1, t1.row2, t2.auxOrder2, t2.row3, t2.row4
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t2 ON (t1.auxOrder1 = t2.auxOrder2)
-- auxOrder1 row1  row2    auxOrder2 row3  row4
-- --------- ----  ------  --------- ----  ------
--         1   12  gfd             1   18    gjkd
--         2   13  jf              2   11    jfyty
--         3   14  gfd
--         4   15  jhhh
```

By the way, why did you create the columns with names such as "row1", "row2"? If it is not intended, I guess that can become confusing.

Comment: it is just name, no matter what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` for this, so it will return all records on the `LEFT` table even if it has no match on the other table.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
            ON a.row1 = b.row3
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cbfb/1)

[For more info: **Visual Representation of Joins**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

**UPDATE 1**

If you are using `SQL Server`

```
SELECT a.row1, a.row2,
       b.row3, b.row4
FROM
  (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY row1 ASC) rn,
           row1, row2
    FROM table1
  ) a LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY row3 ASC) rn,
           row3, row4
    FROM table2
  ) b ON a.rn = b.rn
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aef6f/1)

Answer (score 0):

In order to display unique name and address values from two tables, rather then repeat values when doing a join, this query will take unique values from both tables and display them in order.

This is what I was able to do using oracle 11:

```
select name, address,  table1_id, table2_id 
from 
(
    select table1_id, name,  table_id||(row_number () over (partition by table_id order by name desc nulls last)) as  table1_id_row
    from 
    (
        select distinct table_id table1_id, name
        from table1
        where table_id is not null 
    ) 
) 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
    select table2_id, address,   table_id||(row_number () over (partition by table_id order by address desc nulls last)) as  table2_id_row
    from 
    (
        select distinct table_id table2_id, address, city, state, zip
        from table2
        where table_id is not null
    )
) 
ON table1_id_row = table2_id_row
where table1_id = '123456789' or table2_id = '123456789'
```

Comment: Please try to explain the key elements of your code

Comment: Hope the change helps